# displaying data from database in to text box

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 JSP pages as below:

projectcategory.jsp

```
 <%
    Connection con = DbConnect.connect();
    Statement s = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from projectcategory");
 %>
        <DIV class="TabbedPanelsContent" align="center">
        <TABLE border="1">
            <TR>
                <TH>CATEGORY ID</TH>
                <TH>CATEGORY NAME</TH>
                <TH>Edit/Update</TH>
            </TR>

            <%
                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
            <%String p=rs.getString(1);%>

            <TR>
                <TD><%=rs.getString(1)%></TD>
                <TD><%=rs.getString(2)%></TD>
                <TD>

                <FORM action="EditPcat.jsp?pcatid=p"><INPUT type="submit"
                    value='edit/update'></INPUT>
                </FORM>

                </TD>
            </TR>

            <%
                }
            %>
        </TABLE>
        </DIV>
```

another is Editpcat.jsp:

```
</head>
<body>

<%String s=request.getParameter("p"); %>



<form action="ProjCatServlet" method="post">
<div align="right"><a href="projectcategory.jsp">view</a></div>
<fieldset>

<legend>Edit category</legend>
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Category Id</td>

        <td><input type="text" name="pcatid" value="<%=s%>" ></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td align="right">Category Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="pcatname"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<input type="hidden" name="FUNCTION_ID" value="UPDATE">

</fieldset>
</form>
```

How to display value from one JSP page which we get from database in to text box of another JSP?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing it as a request parameter with the name `pcatid`:

```
<FORM action="EditPcat.jsp?pcatid=p">
```

But you're trying to obtain it as a request parameter with the name `p`:

```
<%String s=request.getParameter("p"); %>
```

Align the names out.

That said, you tagged this question with `servlets`, but you aren't using servlets at all. This code is honestly said a disaster. *Scriptlets* are a poor practice and the JDBC code is leaking resources. Raw Java code belongs in Java classes, not in JSP files. Use taglibs like JSTL to control the page flow and use EL (Expression Language) to access backend data. Go through [those tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html) to get it right.

Kickoff example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Project> projects = projectDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("projects", projects);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("projects.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

and

```
<table>
    <c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project">
        <tr>
            <td>${project.id}</td>
            <td>${project.name}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very dirty but you can add hidden INPUT tags in your form:

```
<INPUT type="hidden" name="p1" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>">
<INPUT type="hidden" name="p2" value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>">
```

BTW: you should close your statement when no longer needed, otherwise you may use too much resources on the server.